# How can I list the contents of a .zip folder in c#?

Tags: c#, list, directory, zip

How can I list the contents of a zipped folder in C#? For example how to know how many items are contained within a zipped folder, and what is their name?

Comment: In case of .NET 4.5 or newer you don't need 3rd party library any more! See my answer below!

Answer (score 41):

.NET 4.5 or newer finally has built-in capability to handle generic zip files with the `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in assembly System.IO.Compression. No need for any 3rd party library.

```
string zipPath = @"c:\example\start.zip";
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine and out of the box without 3rd party components. Be sure to add references `System.IO.Compression.dll` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll`.

Answer (score 35):

[DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) - Zip file manipulation in .NET languages

DotNetZip is a small, easy-to-use class library for manipulating .zip files. It can enable .NET applications written in VB.NET, C#, any .NET language, to easily create, read, and update zip files.

sample code to read a zip:

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(PathToZipFolder))
{
    int totalEntries = zip.Entries.Count; 
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip.Entries)
    {
        e.FileName ...
        e.CompressedSize ...
        e.LastModified...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If you are using .Net Framework 3.0 or later, check out the [System.IO.Packaging Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx).  This will remove your dependancy on an external library.

Specifically check out the [ZipPackage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx).

Comment: It removes dependency on an external library, but the usability of ZipPackage is really not very good. Everything is a trade off!

Comment: `ZipPackage` is tailored to handle mainly those Microsoft related file formats which internally are zip files, such as: `docx`, `xlsx`, `XPS`, `nupkg`... . From generic zip file point of view these only differ because of the presence of `Content_Type.xml` file placed in the root of the archive. If you cannot use .NET 4.5, but can use .NET 3.0, `ZipPackage` can be perfect given that you produce and consume the files.

Comment: For .NET 4.5 or later though should use `ZipArchive` class for generic zip purposes, see my answer below

Answer (score 13):

Check into [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib)

```
ZipInputStream inStream = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(fileName));

while (inStream.GetNextEntry())
{

     ZipEntry entry = inStream.GetNextEntry();
     //write out your entry's filename
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ick - that code using the J# runtime is hideous! And I don't agree that it is the best way - J# is out of support now.  And it is a HUGE runtime, if all you want is ZIP support.

How about this - it uses [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) (Free, MS-Public license)

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipfile) )
{
    bool header = true;
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
    {
        if (header)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Zipfile: {0}", zip.Name);
            if ((zip.Comment != null) && (zip.Comment != ""))
                System.Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", zip.Comment);

            System.Console.WriteLine("\n{1,-22} {2,9}  {3,5}   {4,9}  {5,3} {6,8} {0}",
                                     "Filename", "Modified", "Size", "Ratio", "Packed", "pw?", "CRC");
            System.Console.WriteLine(new System.String('-', 80));
            header = false;
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("{1,-22} {2,9} {3,5:F0}%   {4,9}  {5,3} {6:X8} {0}",
                                 e.FileName,
                                 e.LastModified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                                 e.UncompressedSize,
                                 e.CompressionRatio,
                                 e.CompressedSize,
                                 (e.UsesEncryption) ? "Y" : "N",
                                 e.Crc32);

        if ((e.Comment != null) && (e.Comment != ""))
            System.Console.WriteLine("  Comment: {0}", e.Comment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are like me and do not want to use an external component, here is some code I developed last night using .NET's ZipPackage class.

```
var zipFilePath = "c:\\myfile.zip";
var tempFolderPath = "c:\\unzipped";

using (Package package = ZipPackage.Open(zipFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    foreach (PackagePart part in package.GetParts())
    {
        var target = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(tempFolderPath, part.Uri.OriginalString.TrimStart('/')));
        var targetDir = target.Remove(target.LastIndexOf('\\'));

        if (!Directory.Exists(targetDir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);

        using (Stream source = part.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            source.CopyTo(File.OpenWrite(target));
        }
    }
}
```

Things to note:

- The ZIP archive MUST have a [Content_Types].xml file in its root.  This was a non-issue for my requirements as I will control the zipping of any ZIP files that get extracted through this code.  For more information on the [Content_Types].xml file, please refer to: [A New Standard For Packaging Your Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163372.aspx)  There is an example file below Figure 13 of the article.
- This code uses the Stream.CopyTo method in .NET 4.0

Comment: Which **month and year** for _MDSN Magazine_ ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee310108.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best  way is to use the .NET built in J# zip functionality, as shown in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx. In this link there is a complete working example of an application reading and writing to zip files. For the concrete example of listing the contents of a zip file (in this case a Silverlight .xap application package), the code could look like this:

```
ZipFile package = new ZipFile(packagePath);
java.util.Enumeration entries = package.entries();
//We have to use Java enumerators because we
//use java.util.zip for reading the .zip files
while ( entries.hasMoreElements() )
{
    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();

    if (!entry.isDirectory())
    {
        string name = entry.getName();
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + name + ", size: " + entry.getSize() + ", compressed size: " + entry.getCompressedSize());
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle directories...
    }                        
}
```

Aydsman had a right pointer, but there are [problems](http://https://silverlight.net/forums/p/11394/36407.aspx). Specifically, you might find issues opening zip files, but is a valid solution if you intend to *only* create pacakges. ZipPackage implements the abstract Package class and allows manipulation of zip files. There is a sample of how to do it in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771414.aspx. Roughly the code would look like this:

```
             string packageRelationshipType = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/opc/2006/sample/document";
            string resourceRelationshipType = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/opc/2006/sample/required-resource";
            // Open the Package.
            // ('using' statement insures that 'package' is
            //  closed and disposed when it goes out of scope.)
            foreach (string packagePath in downloadedFiles)
            {
                Logger.Warning("Analyzing " + packagePath);
                using (Package package = Package.Open(packagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    Logger.OutPut("package opened");
                    PackagePart documentPart = null;
                    PackagePart resourcePart = null;

                    // Get the Package Relationships and look for
                    //   the Document part based on the RelationshipType
                    Uri uriDocumentTarget = null;
                    foreach (PackageRelationship relationship in
                        package.GetRelationshipsByType(packageRelationshipType))
                    {
                        // Resolve the Relationship Target Uri
                        //   so the Document Part can be retrieved.
                        uriDocumentTarget = PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(
                            new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative), relationship.TargetUri);

                        // Open the Document Part, write the contents to a file.
                        documentPart = package.GetPart(uriDocumentTarget);
                        //ExtractPart(documentPart, targetDirectory);
                        string stringPart = documentPart.Uri.ToString().TrimStart('/');
                        Logger.OutPut("  Got: " + stringPart);
                    }

                    // Get the Document part's Relationships,
                    //   and look for required resources.
                    Uri uriResourceTarget = null;
                    foreach (PackageRelationship relationship in
                        documentPart.GetRelationshipsByType(
                                                resourceRelationshipType))
                    {
                        // Resolve the Relationship Target Uri
                        //   so the Resource Part can be retrieved.
                        uriResourceTarget = PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(
                            documentPart.Uri, relationship.TargetUri);

                        // Open the Resource Part and write the contents to a file.
                        resourcePart = package.GetPart(uriResourceTarget);

                        //ExtractPart(resourcePart, targetDirectory);
                        string stringPart = resourcePart.Uri.ToString().TrimStart('/');
                        Logger.OutPut("  Got: " + stringPart);
                    }

                }
            }
```

The best way seems to use J#, as shown in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx

There are pointers to more c# .zip libraries with different licenses, like SharpNetZip and DotNetZip in this article: [how to read files from uncompressed zip in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265549/how-to-read-files-from-uncompressed-zip-in-c). They might be unsuitable because of the license requirements.

Comment: no, this is not the best.  The J# runtime is based on an old Java library, the zip stuff has bugs, and it is going out of support.