# openFileDialog Filter only for 24-bit Bitmaps C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to filter `openFileDialog` in C# only for **24-bit** Bitmaps  ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937061/filtering-the-files-shown-in-openfiledialog-based-on-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no. It might be possible to add a filter for this to the Windows Explorer (using rootkit strategies) but this doesn't sound very valueable nor useful for a real world application. Your best bet is allowing the user to pick an image and then checking it right after closing the dialog window.