# C# List of files in an archive

Tags: c#, search, zip

I am creating a FileFinder class, where you can do a search like this:

```
    var fileFinder = new FileFinder(
                         new string[]
                             {
                                  "C:\\MyFolder1",
                                  "C:\\MyFolder2" 
                             }, 
                         new string[]
                             {
                                  "*.txt",
                                  "*.doc"
                             } );
    fileFinder.FileFound += new EventHandler<FileFinderEventArgs>(FileFinder_FileFound);
    DoSearch();
```

If I executed that code, `FileFinder_FileFound` would be called every time a `*.txt` or `*.doc` file was found in `C:\\MyFolder1` and its subfolders, or `C:\\MyFolder2` and its subfolders.

Sot the class looks through subfolders, but I also want it to look through any zip files it comes across, as if they were folders. How can I do this? It would be preferable that no temporary files be created...

**EDIT** Forgot to mention this is not a personal project; its for a commercial application I'm working on with my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [System.IO.Packaging Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) available in .NET 3.5 and higher. You'll find some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307774/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-folder-in-c)

Comment: ZipPackage assumes the presence of a [Content_types].xml in the zip root folder, which maybe not suitable for a generic case. But it works for MS's own formats like xlsx, docx, XPS, nupkg, visx, or if you are the one who creates the zip file using ZipPackage.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use .NET 4.5 or higher you can now finally use `ZipArchive`. It's in the `System.IO.Compression` namespace. The example uses `ZipFile` class too, which requires not just referencing `System.IO.Compression` assembly, but `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly too (both contribute to the same namespace).
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So if your finder encounter a zip file, you can do something like this (the gist of it):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFilePath))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            entry.FullName.EndsWith(".doc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // FileFinder_FileFound(new FileFinderEventArgs(...))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a tool like SharpZipLib: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/. This allows you to list the files in a .zip file and, optionally extract them.

The .NET framework does not natively support using the `FileFinder` to search in .zip files.