# Check files of a zip file exists in another directory

Tags: c#, linq

**No Content check**

I have two directories `C:\Workspace\TestProject\ZipFileA.zip\` as Directory '**A**' and `C:\Workspace\Reports\Latest\` as Directory '**B**' ......Inside directory **A**, multiple Log files are there and inside Directory '**B**' multiple log files are there...

I need to check each log file of Directory 'A' is present in Directory 'B' or not. Incase If any log file of Directory 'A' is NOT exists or doesn't present in Directory 'B' then i need to throw an exception or return false. Basically, files of A directory should be present in 'B' directory. No Issues if 'B' contains additional files which are not in 'A'

How can i check and return bool/throw exception?

Comment: Are you asking about reading the physical directories or something within linq?  I don't understand.  Sorry.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx very long example.

Comment: i updated the question. As the log files within the zipfile to check against the files present in another normal physical directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Intersect method to return values present in both lists

```
var dirAFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\\dirA").Select(s => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s));
var dirBFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\\dirB").Select(s => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s));
var filesInDirAAndDirB = dirAFiles.Intersect(dirBFiles );
```

Don't forget to select the filename only because `GetFiles` returns the full path of the files

To throw an exception just exclude the files existing in A and B from the list of A. If any file exists, you have an error

```
if (dirAFiles.Except(filesInDirAAndDirB).Any())
{
// error
}
```

EDIT:
Other answers that were deleted since were much better since it is not necessary to intersect the file list from both directories. A simple

```
dirAFiles.Except(dirBFiles).Any()
```

is sufficient to find out if any element in dirA exists without being present in dirB.
Oh well, there's not kill like overkill :p

Comment: dirA is basically the zip file path. will the above code works for the check

Comment: Not directly, if you want to use a zip file you need to list its contents and set the value in dirAFiles. To read zip files content please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069092/c-sharp-list-of-files-in-an-archive