# Text Files check within the zip file to another folder

Tags: c#, linq

I've two zip files in a folder

```
C:\WorkUnit\Network\Reports\
```

**Zip files**:

```
LatestReport-20140312_202854-NWTS-a345sfsd3353.zip

LatestReport-20140312_202854-NITS SPACE-d56shj67d3gt8p.zip
```

In each zip file i've few folders and log files

Lets take first zip file: `LatestReport-20140312_202854-NWTS-a345sfsd3353.zip`

Within the zip file and within the subFolders, text files are there.

```
CurrentStack\Unit\NWTS\

Service.txt
SpaceA.txt
SpaceB.txt
```

I need to check these text files at the above location is exists or not at this path `"C:\Collection\LatestFiles\"`

How can i check the textfiles existence(no content check)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check files of a zip file exists in another directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354310/check-files-of-a-zip-file-exists-in-another-directory)

Comment: No Duplicates. its different query

Comment: Do you have any sample code showing your attempted solution?

Comment: as i'm new to C#. I tried with Ziparchive but unable to get the list of files and  compare or check against the directory.