# How to read the contents of a .zip file with VBScript without actually extracting the files?

Tags: vbscript, zip

I have a .zip file that starts with a parent directory. I need to read that dir from the file then search my HD to see if that dir name already exists. If it exists, I then delete it and replace it the contents of the .zip file.

All of this I can do, except read the .zip without actually unzipping the file.

The .zip file can be upwards of 2G in size so I want to avoid unzipping, then reading the dir, then copying.

The reason I don't just unzip directly to the location and force an overwrite is that for some reason when using the `CopyHere` method to unzip, it ignores the switches that would normally force the overwrite and still prompts the user if they want to overwrite.

Code to unzip files:

```
 Set objSA = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 Set objSource = objSA.NameSpace(pathToZipFile).Items ()
 Set objTarget = objSA.NameSpace(extractTo)     

 objTarget.CopyHere objSource,4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can use an external application, try downloading [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and then have your script execute it with the `-l` switch. This should give you some output that you should be able to parse in some way.

Sample from the help file: `7z l archive.zip`

Comment: I think I got this to a semi working state.  Still working on it but this seems the most promising

Answer (score 2):

You can use `For Each` on your `objSource` object, for example:

```
Dim objSA, objSource, item
Set objSA = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objSA.NameSpace(pathToZipFile).Items ()
For Each item in objSource
    WScript.Echo item
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question on SO.
[How to list the contents of a .zip folder in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307774/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-folder-in-c)

I've used this library myself. It works well, http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/,  there is even a treeview example that appears to read the zip without extraction.

You will need the DLLs on the server, but I wouldn't say you have to *install* them. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to read the contents of a zip without extracting it.

If you are just trying to avoid a time consuming copy operation on the data you could try unzipping to a temp directory and then using a "move" function. Move is usually less time consuming than copy as it doesn't actually re-write the data on the disk. It just updates the file system to point at where the data is.

Comment: Everything I have tried does not work.  The problem is that I can have 10 .zip files (software patches) that need to be applied sequentially.  If the system to be patched already has patches 1-5, then I don't need to waste the time doing the unzip, check, delete, try next.  As it stands, that may be what I end up doing.  Either that or convincing the customer that its ok if the users have to hit a button to confirm a overwrite.

Comment: Can you not determine the patch version from the filename of the zip file? Just name the zips something sensible.

Comment: I wish it was that simple.  Each patch has a different starting directory under the zip, that often is not related to the actual patch name.