# Get the available functions/methods of java package in C#

Tags: c#, java, package

I want to know that is it possible to get the classes, functions/methods available in a java package from C#. Suppose I have a java package p which contains SampleClass. I want to inspect this package from C# so that I can get SampleClass. I do not want to use this class in C# in fact I just want to get the name of the available classes and functions.

Hope this is possible!

Thanks

Comment: By "Java package" do you mean a jar file?

Comment: Yes "Java package" -> jar file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a JDK installed, you can use 'jar -tf jarName.jar' to get a list of classes, which you can then parse.

To get more information about a particular class, you can use the command-line 'javap' utility to print out a list of all methods and fields. This is in a fairly easily parsable format. For example:

```
javap -classpath . com.prosc.io.ZipCreator
Compiled from "ZipCreator.java"
public class com.prosc.io.ZipCreator extends java.lang.Object{
    public com.prosc.io.ZipCreator();
    public java.lang.Integer getLevel();
    public void setLevel(java.lang.Integer);
    public void createZip(java.io.File, java.io.File)       throws java.io.IOException;
    public void createZip(java.io.File, java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream)       throws java.io.IOException;
    public void setMaximumZipSize(long);
    static {};
}
```

Comment: When I use javap, it is giving me an error - Error could not find layoutlib. My jar file is placed in d:\javaproject\ and i am using javap in the same directory like: D:\javaproject>javap layoutlib.jar

Comment: You don't pass the name of a jar file to javap, you pass in the name of a class contained inside the jar. Use 'jar -tf jarName.jar' to get the list of classes. Let's say you see a class inside there called /my/cool/Button.class. Use 'javap -classpath jarName.jar my.cool.Button' to see the list of functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about Jar files. It is just a zip file.

You can map folders and files to class names like that: "/java/lang/Object.class" --> "java.lang.Object".

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307774/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-folder-in-c) post you can read about listing the contents of a .zip folder in c#.

The advantage of this method is that you don't need to worry about JDK installed but if you are planning anything complex e.g. list of methods I would go for solution proposed by @Jesse Barnum.