# Restrict users to upload zip file with folder inside

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file upload control.
I restrict users to upload only zip files.
the namespace i use is  **Ionic.Zip;**
I also want check if that zip file has a folder inside.
I have to restrict the users not upload a zipfile with a folder inside.
I could check how many files inside zip file like

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file_path))
{
    if (zip.Count < 5)
    {
    }
```

I do not know how to check for a folder inside

Anyone can help me please.
thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [How to list the contents of a .zip folder in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307774/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-folder-in-c)

Comment: CAn't you extract it to guid folder and check Directories count ?

Comment: How do i do tht? I am new to this. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
var isGood=false;

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(@"c:\\1.zip"))
 {
     for (var i=0;i<zip.Count;i++)
     if (zip[i].Attributes==FileAttributes.Directory) 
      {
       isGood=false;
       break;
      }

 }

 if (isGood) Console.WriteLine ("ok");
 else
 Console.WriteLine ("error");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
```

## edit :

there's seems to be a problem with the way you created this zip file.

I extracted the files from the file you sent me and created new zip : (named 3.zip):

[image]

and as you can see  - the code works :

[image]

so I guess the dll is not powerful enough to recognize edge format

Comment: This did not work. Even though I have a folder inside, it shows false

Comment: can i attach the zip file here? sorry but i do not know how

Comment: @Shanna send it to namir [dott] 78 [at] gmail

Comment: I have sent the file.

Comment: Thank you so much. But wat do i do to restrict the user not to upload a folder inside?

Comment: @Shanna you can't restrict it on the client side ( cross browserly) , but you can upload it to the server and check it there and return a notification notice if it fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate on your zip object's ZipEntries - `ZipEntry` object contains `IsDirectory` property.

```
foreach(var entry in zip)
{
    if(entry.IsDirectory)
    {
        //your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This too did no work . entry.isdirectory shows false