# Zip Archive Equivalent for Directory.GetFiles

Tags: arrays, vb.net, get, archive

I'm trying to get an array of all Zip Archives in a directory and its subdirectories, however Directory.GetFiles() and Directory.GetDirectories() does not work for getting Zip Archives.  And I don't see any obvious options in System.IO.Compression Namespace.  Is there a way to get an array of Zip Archives?

Thanks for the help! :)

Edit 03-17-2015:

My apologies for confusing people with this horribly worded question.  I should have said Zip Files instead of Archives.  So my question, "how do I get a list of all Zip Files in a directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: I suggest you to read the next post : [how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-folder-in-c][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307774/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-folder-in-c

Comment: But how does listing the contents of a zip folder have anything at all to do with the question? The poster is asking how to list all files ending in zip in a starting folder with sub folders. Your answer is not only 100% wrong, but not even relevant to the question in any coherent way.

Comment: My apologies again, Zip Archives was the wrong word to use.  I meant to say Zip Files instead.  In Vb.Net, the file attributes for a zip file are generally listed as Archive, which is why I said that.  So essentially, I am looking for all zip files in a directory.  You are correct, my question is poorly worded.  I will revise and edit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use GetFiles, as it does have a option to traverse sub folders.

The following code will printout all zip files in a starting folder, and sub folders.

```
Dim ar As Array
ar = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\MyZip", "*.zip", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
For Each tok In ar
    Debug.Print(tok)
Next
```

So a wild card of *.zip, and SearchOption of All Directories returns a array of all zip files and includes those in sub folders.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about that.  I actually kind of wish I never asked the question in the first place.  It turned out that I was getting back a list of all Zip Files in the directory I was searching, but my Sub to delete them wasn't working  which made me think I wasn't getting them back in my search.  It turned out to be the Zip Files were labeled as