# How to get all files from archive file in c#?

Tags: c#, gzipstream, deflatestream

I have read email attachment and if archive file then find out how many files are there into archive file. and any exe using programmatically without store any temporary location.
I have find out getting attachment content as string or byte. from this string I need to get all files with its content and filename how this possible.
thanks in advance

Comment: hope  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307774/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-folder-in-c will be helpful for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21767844/853295 I'd use this instead

Comment: `SharpZipLib` or built in if .net is > 4.5

Comment: I think not duplicate because all question is relate to only  Zip file I am asking question about all archive file any type like zip,rar etc any other and not store any temporary location and find all file and find file hash. @Peter please I think it deference question

Comment: If you are asking about "all archive file", then your question is too broad. There's really no point in reopening it...it'll just have to be closed again anyway.